# Memtest shows errors outside of the RAM size

Tags: memory, memtest

I have installed an old **4Gb** RAM module in my laptop and run Memtest86+ v5.01 on it. It showed some errors at addresses **44xxMb-45xxMb**. This is way beyond 4096Mb. Where does the extra memory come from?

[image: memtest]

With a different 4Gb module Memtest shows no errors.

Comment: The solution tot his problem is the same as if it pointed to an address below 4,096.  You will have to run the same tests, multiple times, removing a different module each time.  I would agree the reason it indicates a failure outside of the range you expect is because of hardware memory mapping.

Comment: @Ramhound, there's just one module. And I'm wondering where the extra gigabyte comes from.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate explains what is happening, even I, literally explained it.  It has to do with hardware memory mapping.  The module in question clearly is defective.  You sure the device has a single memory module though, perhaps, one that isn't user replaceable?  It is really odd for a system to have a single memory module.

Comment: In chat, it was mentioned that the wrong mapping can also be due to the slot (channel) the memory is in.  So possible combination of motherboard & ram module hardware mapping confusion. . So other than getting different memory that is on the MB compatability list, you might try to change the location on the channels (slots) of the board.

Comment: @Ramhound, it doesn't explain where the extra gigabyte comes from. As for the second module, I removed it myself and booted with just one.

Comment: @Pastafarianist - So now there is a second module.  I am so confused, you indicated there was a single module, you changing the facts is confusing.

Comment: @Ramhound, what I mean is that prior to testing this module I removed everything else.